# Before Update trigger not capturing all changes

Tags: apex, trigger

```apex
public static void complaintFieldValidation(List<Case> newCaseList, List<Case> oldCaseList){
    for(Case os :oldCaseList){
        for(Case ns :newCaseList){
            System.debug('os.Case_Status__c: '+os.Case_Status__c);
            System.debug('os.FME_Region__c: '+os.FME_Region__c);
            System.debug('os.Region__c: '+os.Region__c);
            System.debug('os.Origin: '+os.Origin);
            System.debug('os.ContactId: '+os.ContactId);
            System.debug('os.Priority: '+os.Priority);
            System.debug('ns.Case_Status__c: '+ns.Case_Status__c);
            System.debug('ns.FME_Region__c: '+os.FME_Region__c);
            System.debug('ns.Region__c: '+os.Region__c);
            System.debug('ns.Origin: '+os.Origin);
            System.debug('ns.ContactId: '+os.ContactId);
            System.debug('ns.Priority: '+os.Priority);
            if((os.Case_Status__c == 'Submitted for Approval' || os.Case_Status__c == 'Open with sales') && (os.Priority == '' || os.FME_Region__c == ''  || os.Priority == null || os.FME_Region__c == null || String.isBlank(os.Origin)) && (ns.Case_Status__c != 'Submitted for Approval' || ns.Case_Status__c != 'Open with sales')){
                ns.addError('Mandatory field should not be Empty/Null');
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Debug Logs:

```
01:44:28.0 (118382676)|USER_DEBUG|[515]|DEBUG|os.Case_Status__c: Submitted for Approval
01:44:28.0 (118433544)|USER_DEBUG|[516]|DEBUG|os.FME_Region__c: null
01:44:28.0 (118481294)|USER_DEBUG|[517]|DEBUG|os.Region__c: null
01:44:28.0 (118534105)|USER_DEBUG|[518]|DEBUG|os.Origin: Web
01:44:28.0 (118618271)|USER_DEBUG|[519]|DEBUG|os.ContactId: null
01:44:28.0 (118677351)|USER_DEBUG|[520]|DEBUG|os.Priority: <None>

01:44:28.0 (118713465)|USER_DEBUG|[521]|DEBUG|ns.Case_Status__c: Reopen
01:44:28.0 (118751632)|USER_DEBUG|[522]|DEBUG|ns.FME_Region__c: null
01:44:28.0 (118789398)|USER_DEBUG|[523]|DEBUG|ns.Region__c: null
01:44:28.0 (118829230)|USER_DEBUG|[524]|DEBUG|ns.Origin: Web
01:44:28.0 (118890434)|USER_DEBUG|[525]|DEBUG|ns.ContactId: null
01:44:28.0 (118926630)|USER_DEBUG|[526]|DEBUG|ns.Priority: <None>
```

I called this method in BeforeUpdate.

When I am clicking on Save button on UI, it is only showing changes in ns.Case_Status__c field in debug logs, for other fields the value is always same, eg: even if I change the value of Origin from 'Web' to 'Email' on UI, it is still showing 'Web' in ns.Origin in debug logs.

Whereas if I change the value of Case_Status__c from 'Submitted for Approval' to 'Closed', it is showing os.Case_Status__c: Submitted for Approval & ns.Case_Status__c: Closed.

Any idea why is it not capturing any changes except Case_Status__c field.

Comment: Your code is wrong - you are using `os` for all your debug statements except case status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Case_Status__c is the value you are referencing from the New values so you are getting the new value which you are saving.

```
System.debug('ns.Case_Status__c: '+ns.Case_Status__c);
```

But for origin field you are using the old value variable so it is not returning the Origin which you are saving.

```
System.debug('ns.Origin: '+os.Origin);
```

Try changing the `os.Origin` to `ns.origin` so you will get the new value as below.

```
System.debug('ns.Origin: '+ns.Origin);
```

One more suggestion instead of passing the old List try to pass the oldMap to the Handler controller so you can avoid one for loop.

Comment: Thanks, could you please code how to do it using Map ?